# DateTime.Parse issue, not support in System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm having an issue where a specific time string, contained in the Gmail Atom feed isn't parsing using `DateTime.Parse()`. I understand I could use DateTime.TryParse(), but I'm curious to why these two don't work, where as all of the rest do.

```
2009-12-28T24:11:48Z
2009-12-30T24:16:20Z
```

the specific exception is:

> System.FormatException: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

My suspicion is that it's because of the hour 24... rather than 00, but I'm not sure how I would rectify that.

Comment: Anyone any idea whether the gmail atom v0.3 feed (https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom) is still returning these incorrect timestamps to this date?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
private static DateTime ParseDate(string s)
{
    DateTime result;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(s, out result))
    {                
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-ddT24:mm:ssK", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        result = result.AddDays(1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I assume since "24" is treated as a literal to be ignored while parsing `Hour` will be `0` and you just add a day to get it to the 24th hour. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

If it IS just the `24` instead of `00`, you can simply replace it and add a day:

```
String s = "2009-12-28T24:11:48Z";
DateTime dt;
if (s.Contains("T24:")
{
    s = s.Replace("T24:", "T00:");

    if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out dt))
        dt.AddDays(1);
}
else
{
    DateTime.TryParse(s, out dt);
}
```

Comment: By doing this you would also need to add one to the day probably after passing.

Answer (score 1):

turns out google's using the w3c date and time standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime, which c# doesnt support? weird, but not that weird.

this project appears to implement that for you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/w3cdate.aspx

edit: yes, I see now that google's not doing it right, but there's an exception for that in the w3cdate c# structure.

Comment: However, that specification declares "hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)".

Comment: They aren't getting correct though. As the doc linked to says an hour of 24 is not allowed. "hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)"

Comment: The `24` in the w3 spec you linked isn't allowed 

`"hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)"`

C# DOES support that standard, but Google is using some other standard or variant. The project you linked does account for it though.

Comment: you guys are correct, however the w3cdate structure linked has an exception for google in the parse function.

Answer (score 1):

[The DateTime entry in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) says that it supports [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which allows both 24 and 00. It should allow the format of type `[YYYY][MM][DD]T[hh][mm]Z` eg. `2010-01-04T14:04Z`.

> Midnight is a special case and can be
>   referred to as both "00:00" and
>   "24:00". The notation "00:00" is used
>   at the beginning of a calendar day and
>   is the more frequently used. At the
>   end of a day use "24:00". Note that
>   "2007-04-05T24:00" is the same instant
>   as "2007-04-06T00:00" (see Combined
>   date and time representations below).

Comment: Unfortunately that's only talking about 00:00 vs. 24:00 (aka midnight) afaik, that is: That exact moment. 24:17 is quite a bit after that and is invalid as far as I can see.

Comment: I think that it will allow `24:00` but not `24:01`.

Comment: Interestingly, in SQL Server query anaylser - this statement fails - DECLARE @timeStamp DATETIME = '2012-01-17 24:00:00'

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as md5sum, but a different way:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(
  "2009-12-28T24:11:48Z",
  new []{ "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK", "yyyy-MM-ddT24:mm:ssK" }, 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None
)
```

You'd still need to check if the date is correct though.

Comment: date returned is `12/27/2009 6:11:48 PM`... I'd assume the -6 hours is from my time zone, but you still need to add a day.