# DateTime error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

When I enter the date in the below format then my db accepts it

`22/06/2011 00:00:00`

But when I enter the date in this format

`mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00`

then my DB throws an error saying `DateTime` not recognised. My calendar gives me `DateTime` in `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format. How can I change that in my code to `dd/mm/yyyy`?

```
   DateTime Res_date = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_DT.Text);

        param[5] = new MySqlParameter("@RespondBy", MySqlDbType.DateTime);
        param[5].Value = Res_date;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RespondBy", Res_date);
```

The `DateTime` is entered in the `txt_DT.text` textbox.

How can I convert the date and then convert the string to `DateTime`?

Comment: How are you inserting it? can you show the code

Comment: All i want is to convert the date from MM dd yyyy to dd MM yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method.  Msdn Documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

```
DateTime Res_date = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_DT.Text, "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss", ... );
```

Then you can use `String.Format` to convert your `DateTime` to any format you want.

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: DateTime pattern 'M' appears more than once with different values. error DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123); String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt); DateTime Res_date = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_RespondBy.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM:ss", null);  how should I do it

Comment: uppercase `MM` is Month, lowercase `mm` is minutes.

Comment: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000343/datetime-parse-issue-not-support-in-system-globalization-gregoriancalendar

Comment: @Mark - If you have something to add, or have tried something new, make note of it in the actual question.